# How to display a 3D point cloud (.ply or .obj file) in my PyQt5 Gui application?

Tags: 3d, pyqt5, point-clouds, open3d

I have a .ply file which I want to create a sort of viewer for in my PyQt5 GUI. Is there any tool that I can use that helps with that sort of thing? Or a separate viewer which I can integrate into my application and it just opens the file with the click of a button in my ui or something like that.

I know of the Open3d Library, but I dont know what I have to use in pyqt in order to display it in my application.

These couple lines of code will open up an interactive window to move my model around.

```py
import open3d

bug = open3d.io.read_triangle_mesh("testModels/Buggy.ply")
open3d.visualization.draw_geometries([bug]) # Visualize the point cloud
```

I want to integrate that window inside my gui in some way. More generally I want a tool that would help me freely view a 3d model inside my PyQt5 application. Fairly new to PyQt so I can't even provide anything I tried as I don't know what PyQt offers in that realm.

Answer (score 0):

For consuming 3D point cloud with Qt GUI, you need to use VTK library it has support for creating a widget and showing 3D point cloud in your app.